# Make trackpad quiet in Yosemite

Tags: macos, terminal, trackpad

In El Capitan there is a setting that allows you to make the click of force touch trackpads (2015 MB. 2015 MBP) silent.

I have tried this out in El Capitan public beta and liked it, however since I use my Yosemite drive as my main partition (because it's not buggy) is it possible to enable this feature on OS X Yosemite 10.10.3 such as a `defaults write` terminal command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe it is possible. Settings for the new trackpads don't exist in Yosemite. And the packaging for the new trackpad specifically states that it requires 10.11 (El Capitan).